# Unexpected token in R with chunks

Tags: r, chunks, unexpected-token

i started a new R Project and everytime I use chunks (regardless from the topic within) the task went trough but i receive an "unexpected token '`" and a red dot in the referring line (see picture)[chunks unexpected token R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6qXN.png).

Also, when my script crushes and/or is reopened all my chunks are gone until I renamed the script.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help

(R version is 4.1.2. "Bird Hippie")

Comment: Is it a R skript or .Rmd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution,

due to a complete R update I had to install the "rmarkdown" (again).

Afterwards (and a run through the code) everything worked out well.

Maybe this issue might be interesting for others too, so I will keep it here :) .